# "systemd-journald: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd)" will cause linux restart?

Tags: rhel, systemd, systemd-journald

I find a machine reboot , and find the last log message is : systemd-journald: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd).  Anybody see this problem ? Will this make machine reboot?

OS version: rhel7.2
systemd version: systemd-219-19 . (default version use rhel7.2)

```
Oct  8 18:35:54 xxxx.localhost su[101957]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Oct  8 18:35:55 xxxx.localhost su[102098]: (to admin) root on none
Oct  8 18:35:55 xxxx.localhost su[102098]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user admin by (uid=0)
Oct  8 18:35:55 xxxx.localhost sudo[102107]:    admin : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin//chmod 666 /tmp/conn_monitor.log.20171008
Oct  8 18:35:55 xxxx.localhost sudo[102110]:    admin : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin//chmod 666 /tmp/conn.log.20171008
Oct  8 18:35:55 xxxx.localhost sudo[102115]:    admin : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin//chmod 666 /tmp/nf_conntrack.log
Oct  8 18:35:55 b31gOct  8 18:38:56 xxxx.localhost systemd-journald: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd).
Oct  8 18:38:56 xxxx.localhost kernel: SELinux:  Disabled at runtime.
Oct  8 18:38:56 xxxx.localhost kernel: type=1404 audit(1507487933.605:2): selinux=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
Oct  8 18:38:56 xxxx.localhost systemd: RTC configured in localtime, applying delta of 480 minutes to system time.
Oct  8 18:38:56 xxxx.localhost kernel: ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Oct  8 18:38:56 xxxx.localhost systemd: Inserted module 'ip_tables'
Oct  8 18:38:56 xxxx.localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
Oct  8 18:38:56 xxxx.localhost syslog-ng[2078]: syslog-ng starting up; version='3.6.4'
Oct  8 18:38:56 xxxx.localhost kernel: kvm-intel-0: apicv enabled.
```

Comment: Ummm...if systemd-journald receives SIGTERM, it will stop logging. So, you won't see any further log messages. Most likely, stopping it triggered a watchdog or an error in some other process and forced a restart. [Systemd-journald man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html#Stream%20logging) also advises against stopping the service. Check further up in the log to see what caused this.

Answer (score 2):

As part of shutting down, it's normal for systemd to shutdown services. In this case, it looks like the logging system was the last service signaled to shutdown, which makes sense.

As the comment suggested, look further back in your logs for something that could have triggered a shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

An error happened during dracut phase (init ram disk). Put "**rd.shell rd.debug**" on the kernel command line to see verbose output and have an emergency shell when this happens.